# Reload TableView from within Custom TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, delegation, uitableview

How can I reload a `TableView` using delegation from within my `CustomTableViewCell` class?

Currently I'm doing it by calling this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

But I would like to do it through delegation so I can have more control over the animation and reload only that specific TableViewCell instead of the whole thing.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Create a protocol, have your view controller implement it and set itself as the delegate on the cell and then call the protocol method from the cell - Have you tried any of this?

Comment: [Check the answer here,you should get the idea of doing it :)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485558/uitextview-and-cell-dynamically-update-height-based-on-content-of-textview/31486972#31486972

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Paulw11 suggests in his comment, you can implement a delegate pattern to call back from your custom `UITableViewCell` to the controller.  Be careful not to create any circular references (use weak properties!)

You could also count on the fact that the `UITableViewCell` is child of the UITableView.  That is, if you need to get to the `UITableView` (vs your controller) you can walk up the superview chain until you find it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is posting a notification that calls a method that will refresh the TableViewCell a bad practice? Or is it just that there's multiple ways to refresh a TableViewCell do this

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a bad practice, no.  Sometimes you just need to be pragmatic and pick what works for the effort you're willing to spend.